# Eclipse does not work with JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/sk/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps.html) about using [Google engine API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) to create web application. 
When I add any file with .jsp suffix into my `war` folder the project will not compile any more.
[image]

What can be the reason ? If you need more information please just leave some comment. Thank you.

Comment: Uhm, what happens if you *just* press Proceed? Otherwise this question makes very little sense to me, sorry.

Comment: @BalusC if I press proceed it will run previous version of the application as if there were no guestbook.jsp.

Comment: What errors exactly are there according to Eclipse?

Comment: @BalusC If it is helpful it seems as if my Eclipse did not know about existence of JSP at all - there is not web project template, no JSP project template... Can it be that I it cannot compile because I did not download "Eclipse for Java EE developers" but only "Eclipse for Java developers" ? in that case how do I upgrade so that it can work with EE staff especially JSP ?

Comment: That would be a good bet.  Try installing the EE version over the existing version.

Comment: @BalusC Strange think is that I cannot get any detail on what errors are there: there are few red underlines in the `.jsp` file saying: `Word XXX is not correctly spelled` but I don't think that is the reason. Even if I delete everything from that file there is still small white cross in red rectangle over the file icon of `guestbook.jsp`(look at the screenshot) indicating that the file has an error. When I change file suffix to `.html` it is all right - the error icon disappears.

Comment: Error details are available in the *Markers* tab in the bottom view.

Comment: @Kelly French: how can I install EE version over existing one ? I don't want to loose any plugins or have to install them again (I have slow connection here Google engine plugin would be installing for days and I have school project due in the morning)

Comment: @BalusC: Great, great comment! I use NetBeans normally Eclipse is very new for me :( So the error in *Markers* tab is *Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs*

Comment: @BalusC @Kelly French: Quick fix for the error in *Markers* tab suggests to "Select a JDK-based 'JRE System library' for your project". Well but I already have JRE System Library [jre6] in my project (see the screenshot).

Answer (score 6):

> *Can it be that I it cannot compile because I did not download "Eclipse for Java EE developers" but only "Eclipse for Java developers" ?*

I'm not sure. I see `<Java EE>` in the title bar in your Eclipse screenshot which is typical for Eclipse for Java EE developers. So you have likely the right version. If you are able to do *File > New > Dynamic Web Project* then you definitely have the Java EE version or at least the one with WTP. More detail can be found in *Help > About Eclipse*.

> *the error in Markers tab is "Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs"*

You need to install the JDK. Go to the [Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) download home page and click the leftmost one of the four big buttons. Done that, go in Eclipse to *Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs*, select the existing JRE, click *Edit* and let the JRE home path point to the JDK folder.

Comment: +1 exactly, that was the problem. I figured it out myself and wanted to post my own answer here but I did not have time and you did it so I'll accept your question in time. I did not have to download JDK I already had it but Eclipse just did not use it - it installed its own JRE instead.

Answer (score 0):

It it asking you if you want to run even though it found errors in the project.  First, what are the errors and can you fix them easily?  Eclipse gives pretty good error messages.  If the errors are from validation, turn them off in the project settings, then try running the project again.

Otherwise, double check that you are using the exact code from the tutorial.  Copy the code from Google and save it into a separate file.  Then select your file, and the new file, right-click on the two files and use Eclipe's file-compare to show you if you missed anything.

[edit]
You could install the EE version to a different directory. Different versions of Eclipse do play nice with each other, they're just huge.  Do *not* import your project into the EE workspace.  It will come across as a plain Java project and you need a Web project.  Create a new Web/JSP project and then copy the files over.

Comment: I copy pasted code from google tutorial into the `guestbook.jsp` file and to be sure I also copy-pasted the name of the file itself. As to error messages - see my comment to the question (above). There are non in the fact :(. Validation run explicitly on the `guestbook.jsp` (right click on file-> Validate) gives following message: `Validation completed with no errors or warnings`.